# Why is UIPopoverController not a UIViewController subclass?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Can you think of particular reasons why Apple chose to implement UIPopoverController as a plain NSObject subclass? To me, a UIViewController subclass would make much more sense, to implement proper UIViewController containment.

But perhaps there are reasons I didn't think of, why Apple's bright engineers made their choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I assume it's because, like UIAlertView, it's presented in a new UIWindow so that's windowLevel property guarantees that it's presented over all content.</strike>

Whether or not it's in a new UIWindow, as far as view controller containment is concerned, you should have no problem using complex parent-child view controller container hierarchies in the view controllers you present in a UIPopoverController. I have view controllers with at least three levels of nesting in [Pillboxie](http://www.pillboxie.com) for some of the popovers, without any problems.

UPDATE: I've checked the hierarchy by logging the classes of the first three levels of the view hierarchy in a sample project, and it is as follows when a popover is visible (my root view controller had two UIButtons):

A WINDOW:

_SUBVIEW CLASS: UIView

___SUBSUBVIEW CLASS: UIRoundedRectButton

**_**_SUBSUBSUBVIEW CLASS: UIButtonLabel

___SUBSUBVIEW CLASS: UIRoundedRectButton

**_**_SUBSUBSUBVIEW CLASS: UIButtonLabel

_SUBVIEW CLASS: UIDimmingView

___SUBSUBVIEW CLASS: _UIPopoverView

**_**_SUBSUBSUBVIEW CLASS: _UIPopoverStandardChromeView

**_**_SUBSUBSUBVIEW CLASS: UIView

Apple's documentation states that the root view controller's view in a UIWindow should have no sibling views managed by other view controllers, because those sibling view controllers will not receive rotation events (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html), second bullet).

So, if Apple had made UIPopoverController a UIViewController subclass, it would have to add it as a child/subview of the rootViewController's hierarchy. But what if the root view controller (which is *your* code, anyway) decides to present a view that interferes with the hierarchy of the UIPopoverController's view? Rather than let us bungle it up, it seems that Apple decided to manage the presentation of the UIPopoverController completely, but in such a way that they did not have to grant themselves an exception to the no-sibling-view-controllers policy of UIWindow.

Comment: The popover is presented in the same window which is needed to make `passthroughViews` work. With view controller containment, I meant that for the root view controller of the popup, `parentViewController` is (probably, haven't tried) not defined. Containment within the various levels of the content view controller of course works but that wasn't my point.

Comment: Your updated answer makes sense. It has to be outside the root view controller's view hierarchy to avoid problems with clipped views. Therefore it can't be part of the UIViewController containment hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

because the `UIPopoverController` objects do not interact with the user, this is why it is not part of the *View* layer, your `UIViewController` is able to communicate with the user, the `UIPopoverController` does not do any similar jobs inside itself.

take a quick look the generic [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) of the *Controller*:

> A controller can send commands to its associated view to change the
>   view's presentation of the model (for example, by scrolling through a
>   document). It can send commands to the model to update the model's
>   state (e.g. editing a document).

it explains why it is not part of the *View* layer, I hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't convince me. It surely interacts with the user when dismissing the popover when the user taps outside the content. Or when shrinking the view to accommodate the keyboard etc.

Comment: the user **cannot** dismiss the popover, the programmer (you) can do it only.

Comment: Of course the user can dismiss it, just by tapping in the screen outside of the popover.